# Kibana Time Filter

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

How do I filter a data range on the dashboard using the Time Picker?

[image]

I am trying to filter log data. And in the logs I have the @timestamp field like this:

[image]

But Kibana does not filter. Whole period data appears.

Comment: Are you sure that you have selected the `@timestamp` field as the time field when creating your index pattern?

Comment: I'm new to Kibana and elasticsearch. It was not me who made the index. How can I know if the @timestamp field is selected as time?

Comment: Go to "Management > Index Patterns", select your index pattern. What do you see at the top if the page where you see "Time Filter field name"?

Comment: ahh. I see "Time Filter field name: searchEndDate"

Comment: Actually, I select the wrong index. In the right index does not show this information.

Comment: So, all good . ?

Comment: Yes.Your tip was very helpful. I'm getting now filters by Time Picker.